# vb.net How can I show in each loop what thread is calculating and continue working in the form?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, loops

I have tried to make a loop inside a thread and, while it is showing me values in a textbox, continue working in my form.
The problem is, when it starts I can not do anything in the form, like pressing buttons or setting commands.

Here is the idea of code:

```
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Form1

    Dim trd As System.Threading.Thread
    Dim cont As Integer

    Private Sub btnOpen_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOpen.Click
            cont = 0
            trd = New Thread(AddressOf trdReadAxis)
            trd.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Delegate Sub CloseFormCallback()
    Private Sub trdReadAxis()
        While cont < 10
            If InvokeRequired Then
                Dim d As New CloseFormCallback(AddressOf trdReadAxis)
                Invoke(d, Nothing)
            Else
                txtXPosition.Text = cont
                cont += 1
                Thread.Sleep(1000)
            End If
      end while
  end class
```

What can I do to see everi second the change in my textbox "txtXPosition"?

Thank you.

Comment: Use `txtXPosition.Update()` or `txtXPosition.Refresh()`... The reason your form and controls are locked down is because you are executing code on the UI thread.

Comment: I would recommend using a [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx) since it is easy to implement and predestinated for such tasks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is a mess:

```
Private Sub trdReadAxis()
    While cont < 10
        If InvokeRequired Then
            Dim d As New CloseFormCallback(AddressOf trdReadAxis)
            Invoke(d, Nothing)
        Else
            txtXPosition.Text = cont
            cont += 1
            Thread.Sleep(1000)
            End If
    End while
End Sub
```

It looks like your worker thread calls itself back via `Invoke`, where it will execute on the UI thread.  Once it is there, it goes through the entire `while` loop-- still on the UI thread-- with a `Sleep(1000)` in every iteration of the loop.  This will lock out the message loop which is supposed to be handling your clicks and keystrokes.

I suggest you divide out the worker thread from the code that updates the textbox, like so:

```
Delegate SetTextCallBack(ByVal message as string)

Private Sub SetText(ByVal message as String)
    if InvokedRequired then
        Dim d As New SetTextCallback(AddressOf SetText)
        Invoke(d, message)
    Else
        txtXPosition.Text = message
    End If
end sub

Private Sub trdReadAxis()
    While cont < 10
        SetText cont
        cont += 1
        Thread.Sleep(1000)
    End while
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice answer! Though I'd just like to point out that `Dim a as Array(1)` is rather superfluous code. [**`Control.Invoke()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1hetckb(v=vs.110).aspx) expects a `ParamArray` so you can pass the variable directly: `Invoke(d, message)` - _OR_ at the most you can do this: `Invoke(d, New Object() {message})`.